# How to update ProgressBar in list view and enable list item when download finishes?

Tags: android, android-layout, in-app-billing

The question says it all. I need to disable the items in list view until an in-app purchase transaction gets over. Once the transaction is over, the download activity would start and download the contents of items (Video files) in a queue.

**So, how do I**

1. Disable the items in the list view until the Android Market isPurchased result is OK.
2. Showup Progressbar in listview (for each list item) and update it as the download progresses.
3. Once a list item's download completes, the onClick of the item would lead to videoPlayer activity.
4. As download completes, each list item would get enabled.

Please help me out!

**Some more info:**
This is a honeycomb based, tablet app. The layout is made of fragments and has category on the left side, the related video titles on the right side! These are the videos that are to be downloaded!